# Type definitions for simple NPM package that generates OAuth 1.0a authorization header for Twitter API using native https nodejs module

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-safety

I added type definitions to a simple [npm package](https://github.com/MauricioRobayo/twitterize). I would love to get some feedback on ways to do better for the type definitions.

The package exports a single function which returns a function that returns a promise:

```js
function request(httpsOptions, body) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(httpsOptions, (res) => {
      let data = ''
      res.on('data', (_data) => {
        data += _data
      })
      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(data))
      })
    })
    req.on('error', (error) => {
      reject(error)
    })
    req.write(body)
    req.end()
  })
}

module.exports = (oAuthOptions) => ({
  subdomain = 'api',
  endpoint,
  requestMethod = 'GET',
  queryParams = {},
  bodyParams = {},
}) => {
  const baseUrl = buildBaseUrl(subdomain, endpoint)
  const body = buildBody(bodyParams)
  const url = buildUrl(baseUrl, queryParams)
  const httpsOptions = buildHttpsOptions(url, {
    requestMethod,
    body,
    baseUrl,
    queryParams,
    bodyParams,
    oAuthOptions,
  })
  return request(httpsOptions, body)
}
```

This is the type definition file that I created:

```js
export type OAuthOptions = {
  api_key: string
  api_secret_key: string
  access_token: string
  access_token_secret: string
}

export type RequestOptions = {
  subdomain?: string
  endpoint: string
  requestMethod?: string
  queryParams?: Record<string, string>
  bodyParams?: Record<string, string>
}

export default function (
  oAuthOptions: OAuthOptions,
): <T>(requestOptions: RequestOptions) => Promise<T>
```

Any advise on how to do better with the type definitions is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Narrow the `requestMethod`** Its type should be narrower. There are only a [small number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) of possible methods. Instead of `string`, you should permit only those which make sense. You probably want something like:

```
requestMethod?: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE' // etc
```

This will both reduce typos (eg, prevent someone from accidentally using `'PUST'`) and make it clear that the method should not just be any string, but one of a few particular strings.

**String params?** You have

```
queryParams?: Record<string, string>
bodyParams?: Record<string, string>
```

But, do both parameters really have to be only string keys with string values? That doesn't sound right. For example, I would hope and expect to be able to do:

```
queryParams: { 1: 'foo' } // turns into `1=foo`
```

or

```
queryParams: { foo: 1 } // turns info `foo=1`
```

or maybe even

```
queryParams: { foo: false } // turns info `foo=false`
```

If the library can handle those sorts of inputs and serialize them properly, which I'd hope it could, the type definitions should reflect that.

---

The JS can be improved a bit too:

**Callbacks** You can pass the `reject` callback alone to `.on('error'`:

```
req.on('error', (error) => {
  reject(error)
})
```

can be

```
req.on('error', reject)
```

**JSON parsing and errors**

```
res.on('end', () => {
  resolve(JSON.parse(data))
})
```

What if `data` happens not to be JSON-parseable? Then an error will be thrown, but the Promise will *not* reject - it'll remain pending forever. Better to enclose that in a `try`/`catch`, and call `reject` if parsing fails.

**Narrower response type?** You currently have:

```
export default function (
  oAuthOptions: OAuthOptions,
): <T>(requestOptions: RequestOptions) => Promise<T>
```

without any constraint on `T`. You might consider explicitly requiring T to be a plain value when deserialized - that is, you wouldn't want people to be able to pass in a function type, or an object type where the object contains non-primitives (other than other plain objects and plain arrays). Maybe use something like `AsJson` in [jcalz's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57859435).

```
type AsJson<T> = 
  T extends string | number | boolean | null ? T : 
  T extends Function ? never : 
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: AsJson<T[K]> } : 
  never;
```

Comment: This is a great code review, really grateful you took the time to provide this feedback.